# Проблема с кнопками на aiogram 2.25.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, sqlite3, callback

У меня в коде проблема: если 2 пользователя запускают свои игры с кнопками, то любой из пользователей может нажать на чужую кнопку и выбрать ответ за другого. я Я пробовал сохранять айди в переменную, но что-то не могу додуматься, как решить проблему(:

Вот часть кода:

```
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
i1 = InlineKeyboardButton("✅", callback_data='gal')
i2 = InlineKeyboardButton("❌", callback_data='iks')
markup.add(i1, i2)
fsb1 = '{:,.0f}'.format(sb1).replace(',', '.')
trks = await message.answer(f"<b>{namefull}:\n{fsb1}</b>", parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=markup)
triks[user_id] = trks
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'gal')
async def triksgal(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE telegram_id = ?', (callback_query.from_user.id,))
user = cur.fetchone()
namefull = f'<a href="tg://user?id={user_id}">{user[2]}</a>'
try:
    if callback_query.from_user.id == user[22]:
        if triks[user_id].message_id == callback_query.message.message_id:
            gal = '✅'
            iks = '❌'
            win = user[23]*2
            fsb1 = '{:,.0f}'.format(win).replace(',', '.')
            await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id,message_id=callback_query.message.message_id,text='Генерация случайного эмодзи...(2-6 сек.)')
```

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-3.x/examples/finite_state_machine.py

Comment: получается через FSM машину состояния можно так сделать? Я просто пока что не всё понимаю(

Comment: да через fsm. Запусти код по ссылке, почупай, станет понятней, что к чему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, описанная вами, связана с тем, что вы сохраняете информацию о кнопках и сообщениях в словаре triks, но этот словарь не ассоциирован с конкретными пользователями. Поэтому, когда несколько пользователей запускают игры одновременно, они могут получить доступ к кнопкам друг друга.

Для решения этой проблемы вам нужно ассоциировать кнопки и сообщения с конкретными пользователями. Вот как это можно сделать:

Создайте словарь, который будет хранить информацию о текущей игре каждого пользователя:

```
user_games = {}
```

При запуске игры добавьте информацию о текущей игре в словарь user_games с ключом, соответствующим user_id:

```
user_games[user_id] = {'message_id': trks.message_id, 'win': user[23]*2}
```

В обработчике колбэков убедитесь, что пользователь, который нажал на кнопку, имеет доступ только к своей игре:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'gal')
async def triksgal(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
    user_game = user_games.get(user_id)

    if user_game and user_game['message_id'] == callback_query.message.message_id:
        # Все остальные действия по игре, включая выигрыш и изменение текста сообщения
        win = user_game['win']
        fsb1 = '{:,.0f}'.format(win).replace(',', '.')
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, mess...)
```

Это позволит каждому пользователю иметь доступ только к своей игре и избежать возможности выбора ответа за другого пользователя.